# Julia Sets in Mathematica

Tags: fractals

stackexchange geniuses!

I'm a high school student doing engineering research and am in need of some technical assistance. I'm working on a paper on using fractals in civil engineering and need to test which Julia Sets would be able to withstand the most pressure.

I have a Mathematica program built so that I can generate the Julia sets, but I have no clue how to check how much pressure they would be able to withstand.

Any guidelines/assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: A Julia set is a mathematical object rather than a physical one.  You'll have to decide how your physical version of the Julia set is to be constructed, and what sort of forces are at work.

Comment: How does one subject a fractal to pressure?

Comment: That's my main issue; I dont know how to "materialize" a fractal into a physical structure in mathematica...any help???

Comment: Use 3D printing [ShapeWays Fractals](http://www.shapeways.com/search?dos=1&shapewaysSearch=fractal). For Julia sets, you'll want to avoid the ones connected by single points. So, pick your points using the Mandelbrot set. Pick points that are well within the "black" area of the Mandelbrot set, and your Julia set will be well-connected.

Comment: @user3564 How did it go? Have you achieved something worth showing?  I mean, it sound rather interesting and exciting!

Comment: Haha wow this was a while ago. It went well. I got 3rd place for math/computer science research and a few other awards. Using menger sponge for large towers was interesed. If you want, I can try to look for the paper I wrote. If you hae more questions just PM me